# Передача данных между процессами анонимным каналом

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть дочерний процесс который собирает названия файлов и записывает их в файл

```
void fun()
{
    DWORD dwBytes;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    out.open("C:\\ConsoleApplication2\\ConsoleApplication2\\file.txt");
    TCHAR filename[] = TEXT("C:\\ConsoleApplication2\\ConsoleApplication2\\file.txt");
    hf = FindFirstFile(L"c:\\FILE11\\screen*", &FindFileData);
    if (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            WriteFile(filename, FindFileData.cFileName, sizeof(int), &dwBytes, NULL);
            out << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }
}
```

Нужно передать эти данные в процесс родитель через CreatePipe , но никак не могу понять как.
Дочерний процесс запускается через CreateProcess который находится в родительском процессе.

```
CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, dwFlags1, NULL, L"C:\\ConsoleApplication2", &ss, &pp);
```